# Display total days between two dates if status is completed

Tags: laravel, date, laravel-5, php-carbon

I am trying to count the number of days between two dates the carbon::now and $start_date and when the status == complete the counting of days stops then get the total number of days.

```
if ($this->status === 'COMPLETED') {
    $now = Carbon::now();
    $start_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->start_date);
    $this->start_date_to_current_date = $start_date->diffInDays($now, true);
}
```

But the problem is, the days still continues to count even the status is completed like for example the total days is 3 then in the next day it becomes 4 then ive tried doing this:

```
if ($this->status == null && $this->status === 'COMPLETED') {
    $now = Carbon::now();
    $start_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->start_date);
    $this->start_date_to_current_date = $start_date->diffInDays($now, true);
}
```

But the value becomes zero. why is that ? :/

Comment: I'm not clearly understand your condition, But I think what you are looking for is `if( $this->status !== 'COMPLETED' )`

Answer (score 2):

You need to log the complete date somewhere, and use it instead of `now()`.

For instance:

```php
if ($this->status === 'COMPLETED') {
$start_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->start_date);
$start_date->diffInDays($this->completed_date); // completed_date should come from db.
}
```

The problem here is that you're using the current date as complete date which is obviously changing everyday, hence you get different result each day.

Comment: But how can i put the current date to the completion date field ? 
i mean i want to count the number of days between $start_date and current date.

Comment: I think you need to store current date in the database when the status is changed to 'COMPLETED'. For me, it does not make sense to find the diff between start and current date. Maybe your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

let it only do that when you not yet, and do not repeat do it.

```
`if ($this->status == null && $this->status !== 'COMPLETED') {`

`$now = Carbon::now();`

`$start_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->start_date);`

`$this->start_date_to_current_date = $start_date->diffInDays($now, true);`
```

`}`